# Can I embed video content using htmlBody and htmlService in Apps Script for a Gmail message

Tags: html, google-apps-script, embed

I'm using Google Apps Script to automatically email people.  I want to be able to embed a video in the gmail message.

I'm creating the html output using

```
HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('emailTemplate').getContent()
```

and assigning that to the parameter "htmlBody" in the GmailApp.sendEmail method.

the html of the emailTemplate is:

```
<html>
 <body>
  Thankyou for your submission. The return have been processed and your dashboard is attached.<br><br>
  <iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/XXXXXXXXXXX/preview" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

If I view the html file using notepad in Chrome the video works but when it is incorporated into the email message I get the body text but the video is just a blank iframe

How do I get the video to work?

thanks

Comment: Did you try to build the htmlBody with your embedded video without using HtmlService?

Comment: I built it in notepad in the fist instance, checked it worked in Chrome then pasted into an HTML tab in Apps Script.  I haven't actually tried stringing together all the html as one string directly as the htmlBody parameter, if that's what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that what I meant, sorry... Haven't tested yet, but since it's HTML you can give it a try

Comment: Just tried it,   unfortunately, didn't work. Any other ideas?